# How to fix:Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have compiled the below code it's getting me the Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."
Error Don't know why.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import EditableContetnt from './Fuck';
import Mymenu from './Mymenu';
import 'react-contexify/dist/ReactContexify.min.css';
import { MenuProvider } from 'react-contexify';


class App extends Component
{
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state={name:'Hello World'};
  }
  render()
  {
    const {name}=this.state;
    console.log(name);
    return(
      <div>
        <MenuProvider id="menu_id">
            <EditableContetnt {name}/>
        </MenuProvider>

        <Mymenu/>
      </div>
    )
  }
} 

export default App;
```

when i run the module it shows Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

Comment: Which line gives you this error?

Comment: Try `<EditableContetnt name={name} />` or `<EditableContetnt {...this.state} />`

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass your  `name` variable to `MenuProvider` component different way. Like this:

```
<EditableContetnt name={name} />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change: import 'react-contexify/dist/ReactContexify.min.css';

to

import './react-contexify/dist/ReactContexify.min.css';

(if it's in the same directory)